# passing object to layout view undefined sails js

Tags: node.js, layout, sails.js, view

Am trying to count the number of user by color

my code is on the userController.js

```
'dashboard': function(req, res) {

var totalAvailable = user.count({
      value: 'blue'
    }).exec(function countCB(error, found) {
      console.log(found);

    });

    res.view({totalAvailable});


  },
```

when I refresh the dashboard it counts the number of user with value blue in the console which is 50 now I want to show 50 on my dashboard view the

I have used `<%= totalAvailable %>`

on the page it says undefined on the console it outputs 50

Answer (score 0):

This is never gonna work. because The functions like **find,findOne,count,create,destroy** in sails are asynchronous and does not return anything.

That one was the first issue in your code,The other one is `res.view()`,this function is used to  render the templates(**.ejs** files) instead of array of jsons. The correct way to get it done is.

```
'dashboard': function(req, res) {
  //The correct way.
  var totalAvailable;
  user.count({value: 'blue'})
    .exec(function countCB(error, found) {
      console.log(found);
      res.ok(found);// not this--> res.view({found});
    });
},
```

> The above code is correct method.
>
> res.view() is executed after result is populated in **found**.
>
> **Another wrong way i am mentioning as follows.**

```
'dashboard': function(req, res) {
  //This is extremely wrong way never do this
  var totalAvailable;
  user.count({value: 'blue'})
    .exec(function countCB(error, found) {
      console.log(found);
      totalAvailable=found;
    });
  res.ok(totalAvailable);
}
```

this is wrong way because **count()** is asynchronous function which will not be pushed on execution stack. Instead Asynchronous functions are appended to event queue with some timeOut (waiting time in queue).

While non-asynchronous functions are directly pushed to execution stack and get executed.
So res.ok() is not blocked and get executed first before **user.count()** populates results.

**So always do think in terms of synchronous nature while doing code in node**

read these.
https://www.codementor.io/nodejs/tutorial/manage-async-nodejs-callback-example-code
https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-best-practices/

And official nodejs docs https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/